# jquery dialog box doesn't work in accordion mvc razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I am working on razor project where I need to display jquery modal popup. The popup shows up fine when it's not started from the accordion, but once I put it there, the button doesn't show the popup, but instead triggers the function from different button.

I have this in the markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ASPXView", "Report", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, 
         "Password change was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
        @Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Report.Id)
        <div id="accordion">

            @foreach (var item in Model.Parameters)
            {
                <h3><a href="#">@Html.LabelFor(m => item.Name, item.Prompt)</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        Search @*Html.TextBox("Search")*@ 
                        <input id="@("Search" + item.Name)" type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("QuickSearch/" + item.Name, "Report")" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <select multiple id="@("Select" +item.Name)" name="@("Select" +item.Name)"></select>                           
                    </div>

                    <div class="removed">                     
                     <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>               
                    </div>              
                </div>
            }         
        </div>
        <p style="text-align: right">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </div>
}
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>Test Content.</p>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var openDialog = function () {

        $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons', {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            }
        });


        $('#dialog').dialog('open');

    };
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });
        $('#opener').click(openDialog);
    })

</script>
```

As I said, when I'll place Open Dialog  below the dialog div, outside of accordion div, the popup comes up normal, but once I put the button there, popup doesn't come out.

Thanks in advance for every advice

---

JS CODE UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#opener').click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
            $("#dialog").attr("title", "Your Title Heren");
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                height: 620,
                width: 700,
                modal: true
            });
        });

    })
</script>
```

After replacing the code I had with this code, I can see the popup only from the 1st item in the accordion, but not from the other two. 
Also, once the popup shows up on the screen, postback is happening, and event which is attached to another button, the submit button happens. Why do you think is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you should have your jQuery Like this

```
$('button[id^=opener]').click(function (){
 $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
    $("#dialog").attr("title", "Your Title Heren");
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        height: 620,
        width: 700,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

## Edited:

Mark up should go like this

```
@int i = 0;
 @foreach (var item in Model.Parameters)
        {
          // your rest of the Code
                <div class="removed">                     
                 <button id="opener"+i>Open Dialog</button>               
                </div>              
            </div>
i++;
        }
```

jQuery Selector will be Like this

```
$('button[id^=opener]').click(function (){
// Rest Continues
```

Comment: please check my edited code and the description below that, explaining what's happening. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: $("#dialog").dialog('destroy'); would destory the dialog and the event in 'openDialog' just does  'open', getting rid of the destroy will make the dialog open multiple times.

Comment: @HaBo you mean the id of the button, in this case 'opener'? Thanks

Comment: @HaBo now the code doesn't do anything, it even doesn't show the popup. Please find here the complete code, maybe you can find out why is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/laziale/EA2Dg/7/ Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: Check you Source code on browser, how the IDs for button are created, if that didn't create IDs like opener0, opener1,opener2 then change the code to <button id="opener@(i)">Open Dialog</button>

Comment: @HaBo the IDs are correct now with the last correction, but that again triggers the form submit method, instead of dispaying the popup window.

Comment: better flip the button tag and replace it with some anchor link <button id="opener"+i>Open Dialog</button> replace with <a id= "opener@(i)" class="OpenDialogClass" href="#" >Open Dialog</a> this will stop Form submit trigger and you can style the link to look like button in CSS using the Class .OpenDialogClass{ width:100px; height:30px; backgroung:#c30; #fff;}

Comment: Once you do that, Do not forget to change this $('button[id^=opener]').click(function (){ to $('a[id^=opener]').click(function (){

Comment: @Habo now the links are not doing anything, please check the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/laziale/EQwdf/ Thanks a lot man

Comment: @Laziale please check the browser rendered mark up. this is perfect. This should work with out any problem.

Comment: @Laziale How did it go. was my answer useful?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7565/discussion-between-laziale-and-habo)

Comment: I guess by now you got the answer :) mark this as answer if this was useful.